# Problema con character_set_connection en consulta Select date_format() desde Php a MySql (retorna caracteres chinos)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Antecedentes: Tengo la siguiente consulta en un script PHP

```
SELECT date_format('2022-09-04 22:23:00', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

- Testeo en Localhost directamente desde el cliente MySql y el resultado
  es correcto: 2009-10-04
- Testeo en Localhost el script PHP y el  resultado es correcto: 2009-10-04
- Testeo en el servidor público directamente de PHPMyadmin y el resultado es correcto: 2009-10-04
- Testeo en el servidor público el script PHP y el resultado es **圀 ????b**
  (caracteres chinos o país oriental)

**Otros antecedentes**

- Solo pasa con date_format, cualquier otra consulta a fecha resulta
  correcta, por lo que es posible que character_set_connection sea el
  problema, no obstante no sé cual es la configuración correcta ya que
  en MySql 8.0 no existe utf8_general_ci (que es lo
  habitualmente utilizaba para mis tablas de datos) y tampoco se muy
  bien como arreglarlo.
- El script tiene cabecera PHP charset=UTF-8
- El script incluye:

  $this->pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

**Este es el resultado de los character set de MYSQL Localhost**

- character_set_client      utf8
- character_set_connection  utf8
- character_set_results     utf8
- collation_connection      utf8_general_ci

**Este es el resultado de los character set de MYSQL servidor público**

- character_set_client utf8mb4
- character_set_connection utf8mb4
- character_set_results utf8mb4
- collation_connection **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** <-- ¿Por aquí irá el problema?
- character_set_database **utf32** <-- ¿esta bien?
- character_set_filesystem binary
- character_set_server utf8mb4
- character_set_system **utf8mb3** <-- ¿esta bien?

(Trabajando con PHP 8.1.7, MySql 8.0, Ubuntu 22)

Bueno, se agradece de antemano vuestra ayuda.

Comment: el archivo php esta en utf-8 SIN BOM???

Comment: intenta usar una chartset en tu coneccion asi: `$con='mysql:host=example.com;dbname=testdb;port=3306;charset=utf8mb4';`

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Gracias por tu comentario. Así es está sin BOM. (lo probé en UTF-8,UTF-8 sin BOM, y ANSI ). También intenté con charset=utf8mb4 en la conección pero pasa lo mismo. Mi hipótesis sigue siendo lo de la "collation_connection" pero no he encontrado como solucionarlo.

Comment: lo que estas preguntando en cada linea si esta bien o mal ... se supone que todos deben estar en utf8mb4 incluso tu local...